# What is wrong with this piece of code(descriptive program)?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am trying to fetch the count of tables present on a website. I am executing this code through QTP, but I get the count zero.

```
Set my_page=Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*")
Set table_desc= description.Create
table_desc("html_tag").value="TABLE"
Set all_tables=my_page.ChildObjects(table_desc)
total_no_tables=all_tables.count
msgbox total_no_tables
```

What should I need to add in order to get the table count?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the tag you're looking for doesn't actually have an underscore in it...

i.e. GUISpy generates this: `"html tag:=TABLE"`

but you're using `"html_tag"`

Try taking out the underscore.

```
table_desc("html tag").value="TABLE"
```